# JavaScript loop variable scope

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

The problem is the scope of a for-loop. Each click on the arrow buttons, the picture of the car should change to the desired angle. But this does not happen. Because the variable `i` in the for-loop is in local scope. I try to solve this problem with a global object like `window`, but this didn't work. (Please use example maximized)

Thank you in advance!

```js
function myFunction() {
  const imageNumber = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
  const imageColor = ['pearl-white', 'ruby-black-pearl', 'alloy-silver-metallic', 'mercury-gray-metallic', 'red-diamond', 'quartz-brown-metallic'];
  const img = document.querySelector('#image');
  const colorButton = document.querySelectorAll('#color');
  const next = document.querySelector('#next');
  const prev = document.querySelector('#prev');
  let index = 0;

  img.setAttribute('src', 'https://mcarsstatic.cachefly.net/img/vehicles/phev/2020/trims/GT-S-AWC/360/' + imageColor[index] + '/2020-phev-360-' + imageNumber[index] + '-d.png');

  for (let i = 0; i < colorButton.length; i++) {
    colorButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      img.setAttribute('src', 'https://mcarsstatic.cachefly.net/img/vehicles/phev/2020/trims/GT-S-AWC/360/' + imageColor[i] + '/2020-phev-360-' + imageNumber[index] + '-d.png');
    });
  }

  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    index++;
    if (index >= imageNumber.length) {
      index = 0;
    }
    img.setAttribute('src', 'https://mcarsstatic.cachefly.net/img/vehicles/phev/2020/trims/GT-S-AWC/360/' + imageColor[i] + '/2020-phev-360-' + imageNumber[index] + '-d.png');
  });

  prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    index--;
    if (index <= 0) {
      index = imageNumber.length - 1;
    }
    img.setAttribute('src', 'https://mcarsstatic.cachefly.net/img/vehicles/phev/2020/trims/GT-S-AWC/360/' + imageColor[i] + '/2020-phev-360-' + imageNumber[index] + '-d.png');
  });



}
myFunction();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.img-item {
  position: relative;
}

div.img-item>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

div.arrow-item {
  height: 462px;
}

span#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span#prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.colors {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#color {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1 arrow-item">
        <span id="next"><</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 img-item">
        <img id="image">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 arrow-item">
        <span id="prev">></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="colors">
          <div id="color" style="background-color: white;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: black;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: silver;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: gray;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: red;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: brown;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And please ask a question following the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, it's because of the scope. And setting `i` to global doesn't help, because you're using `i` outside of the loop, and in that stage the value of `i` will be off the indices of `imageColor` array.

Comment: On click use imageColor[index] in place of imageColor[i]

Comment: Js objects  help  to solve this problem or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click handler you need to store the selected color in a separate variable, e.g. `selectedColor`.

Furthermore, it is not allowed to use the same **`id`** value more than once. I did not fix this because it wasn't needed for the snippet to work, but it is something you better take care of in order to prevent the code from 'mysteriously' not working in some browsers.

Fixed code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const imageNumber = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
  const imageColor = ['pearl-white', 'ruby-black-pearl', 'alloy-silver-metallic', 'mercury-gray-metallic', 'red-diamond', 'quartz-brown-metallic'];
  const img = document.querySelector('#image');
  const colorButton = document.querySelectorAll('#color');
  const next = document.querySelector('#next');
  const prev = document.querySelector('#prev');
  let index = 0;
  let selectedColor = 0;

  img.setAttribute('src', 'https://mcarsstatic.cachefly.net/img/vehicles/phev/2020/trims/GT-S-AWC/360/' + imageColor[selectedColor] + '/2020-phev-360-' + imageNumber[index] + '-d.png');

  for (let i = 0; i < colorButton.length; i++) {
    colorButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      selectedColor = i;
      img.setAttribute('src', 'https://mcarsstatic.cachefly.net/img/vehicles/phev/2020/trims/GT-S-AWC/360/' + imageColor[selectedColor] + '/2020-phev-360-' + imageNumber[index] + '-d.png');
    });
  }

  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    index++;
    if (index >= imageNumber.length) {
      index = 0;
    }
    img.setAttribute('src', 'https://mcarsstatic.cachefly.net/img/vehicles/phev/2020/trims/GT-S-AWC/360/' + imageColor[selectedColor] + '/2020-phev-360-' + imageNumber[index] + '-d.png');
  });

  prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    index--;
    if (index <= 0) {
      index = imageNumber.length - 1;
    }
    img.setAttribute('src', 'https://mcarsstatic.cachefly.net/img/vehicles/phev/2020/trims/GT-S-AWC/360/' + imageColor[selectedColor] + '/2020-phev-360-' + imageNumber[index] + '-d.png');
  });
}

myFunction();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.img-item {
  position: relative;
}

div.img-item>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

div.arrow-item {
  height: 462px;
}

span#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span#prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.colors {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#color {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1 arrow-item">
        <span id="next"><</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 img-item">
        <img id="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 arrow-item">
        <span id="prev">></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="colors">
          <div id="color" style="background-color: white;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: black;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: silver;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: gray;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: red;"></div>
          <div id="color" style="background-color: brown;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Peter B very much.Its really help me.